# replace awkward characters in string php

Tags: php, string, special-characters, replace

Is there a string functions which replaces all the awkward characters, like

Hellö becomes Hello,

Or do i need the following strtr function, and put all the awkward characters in the...?

```
$addr = strtr($addr, "äåö", "aao");
```

Comment: Can you specify more precisely what you mean by "awkward characters"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming by "awkward characters" you mean anything that is not ASCII. If so, then try [`iconv`](http://ideone.com/bN8H3):

```
$addr = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $addr);
```

The first argument is the character set of the input string.

```
$addr = "Hellö";
echo $addr . "\n";
$addr = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $addr);
echo $addr . "\n";
```

Output

```
Hellö
Hello
```

See it run at [ideone](http://ideone.com/bN8H3).

Comment: don't do this ... if the text contains valid UTF-8, it will get converted as well

Comment: @ajrael: What this does is to take the characters that are not valid ASCII and convert them as best as possible to valid ASCII.

Comment: Yup, at the meantime, it also replace valid UTF-8 to `?`. However, is depend on OP environment setting.

Comment: Is it safe then...? What to do...? Regards!

Comment: If you page encoding is iso-8859-*, please go ahead

Comment: Hi i cannot get rid of the é If the LastName = Boerée I get Boer?e @ the output...?   $clean_lastname = $Author->LastName;
      
 $clean_lastname = htmlspecialchars_decode($clean_lastname);
 $clean_lastname = strtr($clean_lastname, 
  "ÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÑÒÓÔÕÖØÝßàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïñòóôõöøùúûüýÿ",
  "AAAAAACEEEEIIIINOOOOOOYSaaaaaaceeeeiiiinoooooouuuuyy");
$clean_lastname = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $clean_lastname);
$clean_lastname = strtolower($clean_lastname); echo $clean_lastname;

Comment: @Thijs - **do not apply both, and discard use of htmlspecialchars_decode**, use either one will do. And update your question with the latest code,not at comment